# Linux command for removing all ~ files

Tags: linux, file-io

What command can I use in Linux to check if there is a file in a given directory (or its subdirectories) that contains a `~`at the end of the file's name?

For example, if I'm at a directory called `t` which contains many subdirectories, etc, I would like to remove all files that end with a `~`.

Comment: It may *seem* to work, @Shadow, but I think that's because you're doing it wrong :-) If you run that command in a directory with an x~ file, the *shell* will expand *~ to x~ before rm ever sees it - that means no subdirectories will be done. And, if there's no VIM backup files in the current directory, the shell complains.

Answer (score 9):

Watch out for filenames with spaces in them!

```
find ./ -name "*~" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: `-type f` Yeah. That's best, but rm -f will silently skip them anyway.

Comment: What does -print0 | xargs -0 mean?
and where should the type -f go?

Comment: print0 and the -0 for xargs, use a NULL to terminate each filename in the stream. Without those two things, a file "a b c.txt" is treated as three files "a", "b" and "c.txt". And I put the -type f in, and upvoted since it's now a better answer :-)

Answer (score 8):

with GNU find

```
find /path -type f -name "*~" -exec rm {} +
```

or

```
find /path -type f -name "*~" -delete
```

Comment: +1, both of these solutions avoid forking off a new process for each file to be removed; the second is slightly better, since it will never run into the problem of command line length limits if you're removing a very large number of files.

Answer (score 2):

```
find ./ -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Here `find` will search the directory `./` and all sub directories, filtering for filenames that match the glob '*~' and printing them (with [proper quoting courtesy of alberge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236618/linux-command-for-removing-all-files/1236632#1236632)). The results are passed to `xargs` to be appended to `rm -f` and the resulting string run in a shell. You can use multiple paths, and there are many other filters available (just read `man find`).

Answer (score 1):

you can use a find, grep, rm combination, something like

find | grep "~" | xargs rm -f

Probably others have better ideas :)

Comment: This one would also remove a~b etc